# Este script só faz o controle no carregamento da página, Como posso fazer esse controle durante toda a navegação?

Tags: jquery

Este script faz o controle da existência da classe `hide-bar` no id `header` no carregamento da página quando a classe ainda não esta adicionada ao mesmo. Preciso encontrar uma solução para que assim que a classe for adicionada ao id que é exatamente quando existe uma rolagem da página, o script seja executado.

```
jQuery(function($){

    $( "#header", function() {
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        if ( $("#header").hasClass("hide-bar") ){
             alert("A classe está adicionada.");
        }

    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa "ouvir" o evento scroll/rolagem.

Pode fazer assim:

```
 $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($("#header").hasClass("hide-bar")){
         alert("A classe está adicionada.");
    }
});
```

Dessa maneira quando o evento acontecer ele vai chamar esse código e fazer a verificação.

Se precisar saber a posição do scroll, pode usar `$(window).scrollTop();` que lhe vai dar o valor do scroll no momento.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius ótimo! Se quiser pode também usar `$(window).scrollTop()` para saber a posição do scroll.